# naming conventions for html elements

Tags: asp.net, html, naming-conventions

I have a general query regarding name of html elements.

I have seen in the past developers placing an prefixes before the id of their html elements eg for a div element -> dvMyDiv

I have seen a mix of casing when naming elements. Similar to that of assigning name to element classes.

So I am wondering is there any standard or convention to what html elements should be named? What casing? Should they have prefixes etc?

I am working with asp.net web forms, html5, css3 and jquery so would like some form of standard for naming conventions that I can share with other developers.

Comment: Are you referring to HTML ID and class names or .NET control IDs?

Comment: “I have seen in the past developers placing an prefixes before the id of their html elements eg for a div element -> dvMyDiv” — I hate that. Unnecessary coupling of the class name to the type of element it’s used on. In HTML, you can see the type of element right there. In CSS, if it’s important what type of element it is, then select the element too, i.e. `div.MyDiv`. If it’s not important, don’t clutter up the class name with a prefix just because you’re trying to apply an idea that seemed good in C. (See the “I’m Hungary” section in http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html).

Comment: On the other hand, *meaningful* class/ID prefixes that have use in your specific site/application, and are documented and consistently applied, fair enough.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/a/23658906/759452

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with consistency - if you already have a convention, then stick to it.

However, if your making a new convention, this kind of Hungarian notation can be a really bad idea because it's not at all DRY. For example, the name of the tag is `<div>` and then the name of your class again says that it's a div. If you change from using `<div>`s to `<section>`s, either your code will be out of date or you'll have to change all the class names as well (possibly in HTML, CSS and JavaScript). Since you can target classes using code like `div.classname`, it adds absolutely no value.

A better idea is to name things after the type of content they include. For example, in a blog, you might use HTML like this:

```
<section class="posts">
  <article id="post-1" class="post">
    <h1>Post Title</h1>
    <div class="post-content">
      <p>Blah blah blah</p>
      <p>Blah blah blah</p>
    </div>
    <time class="timestamp">17th January 2012</time>
  </article>
  <article id="post-2" class="post">
    <h1>Post Title</h1>
    <div class="post-content">
      <p>Blah blah blah</p>
      <p>Blah blah blah</p>
    </div>
    <time class="timestamp">18th January 2012</time>
  </article>
</section>
<aside class="top-posts block"></aside>
<aside class="contact-form block"></aside>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard you and your colleagues should decide what format you want to use and stick with it. The prefixes thing is kind of Hungarian notation. But I don't really like it. Just make sure the names are clear and descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

**REVISED:**
After reading the Wiki article it appears a lot of very well-known developers and Microsoft no longer recommend Hungarian Notation.

---

I am led to believe that [Hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) is a very popular naming convention. Also, I believe that it is the recommended and used convention from Microsoft.

I suppose the most important thing is consistency. You should choose a convention and stick with it.

Comment: See the “I’m Hungary” section of http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html for a good discussion of the history, purposes and misuse of Hungarian Notation.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not Hungarian notation.

I would recommend using semantic HTML http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML as it makes your HTML code easier to read.